# PERL: Using REGEX to match a string without the first token repeated in the string. (ABC, not AAA ABC)

Tags: perl

I am relatively new to perl and I apologize in advance if this question is simple and I am missing something completely obvious, however, I've been looking around for the answer for a couple of days now and can't find a solution.

I am trying to use a regular expression to match the FIRST instance where A is followed by C without another A in between A and C. Note that in this text string there are other instances following the first A.C combination that could also fit the A.C, (specifically note the ADC) Here is the text:

```
$text = "AAA ABC ADE AFG ADC AHI AJK AIZ XXB NBV";
```

I first tried:

```
@finds1=$TEXT=~m/(A.*?C)/;
$result = $finds1[0];
print "result = $result\n";
```

This prints the following:

```
result = AAA ABC
```

When what I want is just:

```
result = ABC
```

Note that I am trying to create a regular expression that could be used where B could be any string of characters.  For example ADC, AFGHJKC, AYUIOKJHGTC.

I next tried to use a look-forward combined with an if then else statement.  Here is the code:

```
@finds1=$TEXT=~m/(A(?(?!.*?A.*?C).*?C|Z{100}))/;
$result = $finds1[0];
print "result = $result\n";
```

The first part of the REGEX, (A, tells perl to find an occurrence of A. Once found, perl then processes the if then else statement where the conditional statement is that there are no instances of .*?A.*?A following the A, if none are found then perl looks for .*?C, if at least one is found, then it searches for 100 instances of Z. (my way of getting Perl to move on since neither in this text nor in the text I'm trying to parse are there 100 Zs.)

This returns:

```
result = ADC
```

I have considered using a positive look-behind after identifying C for the first time.  However, like I mentioned above, The number of characters between the first A.C combination without an A in between them is variable.  As far as I know PERL can't do variable-length look-behinds.

Any help or direction you could provide would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Am I wrong in my interpretation that /A[b-zB-Z]*?C/ would fit the bill?

Comment: You are correct.  It does work on this text.  Thanks for your response.  How would you modify it to accommodate spaces between the A and the C (e.g. $text = "AAA A B C ADE AFG ADC AHI AJK AIZ XXB NBV";

Comment: Here, I'll expand upon it so that it's answer-worthy, and answer your question there as well.

Comment: Like so:  /A\s*[b-zB-Z]*?\s*C/

Comment: Really, there's absolutely no reason to be that complicated. /A[b-zB-Z\s]*?C/ works as well, and is a lot simpler.

Comment: Not that you would ever exaggerate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're wanting:

- An "A"
- Followed by any number of characters that aren't A
- Followed by a "C"

This can be achieved with the regular expression

`/A[B-Z]*?C/`

Characters in square brackets `[]` represent a character class. With a character class you can tell the regex engine to match only one out of several characters. Simply place the characters (or ranges of characters) you want to match between square brackets (http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Say you wanted to do this with another letter, Q, you would have a slightly different character class

`/Q[A-PR-Z]*?C/`

If you wanted to modify it to accommodate spaces between the A and the C, you can approach it in two different ways. You can negate a character class, and it will match *any* character apart from the ones in it, like so:

`/A[^AC]*C/`

Which will match an A, then any number of characters apart from A and C, then a C.

OR, you can add a space to the original character class, like so:

`/A[B-Z ]*?C/` (note the space after the Z)

If you want any sort of whitespace, replace the space with \s, which represents any whitespace, like so:

`/A[B-Z\s]*?C/`

Comment: thanks for the great answer.  You are right. My questions was quite simple.  Although your answer answers how I phrased my question, it doesn't quite address my problem. This is completely my fault. What would better address it is if I had made the text as follows: "$text = ate ate ate ate bat cat ate dog egg ate for gin ate dog cat ate;" Now instead of extracting ABC I want to extract the first time ate is followed by cat without an ate between the ate and cat.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely more difficult!

Comment: Any ideas on how to handle it? Do you think I should post a new question with the updated text? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I'll think about it. I think I know how I'd do it, but it might not be the most efficient or pretty regex in the world.

Comment: At this point, I'd take the ugliest, working piece of code out there.

Comment: I've got one. If you post a new question and link me to it, I'll answer it :)

Comment: Here is a link to the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321307/using-regex-to-match-a-string-without-the-first-token-repeated-in-the-string-p

Answer (score 3):

Don't you simply want

```
/A[^AC]*C/
```